# I think I have misunderstood the idea behind front-page.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm entirely new to WordPress but have been tasked with creating a website for my uncles business. I'm trying to understand a bit more about the mechanics of WordPress before I do any more coding so I have a question about index.php / front-page.php.

I had been working on index.php before I even decided to implement WordPress so everything is hard coded. So at the moment I have a fully populated index.php file that I custom designed myself. My understanding of WordPress so far is that everything is dynamic. So I feel like what I *should have done* is created a front-page.php with a function within it to call the static 'Front page' that I create within the WordPress GUI, then outputting it using the_content();?

Is it okay to have hard-coded in WP, or is this against best practice? Obviously with my current implementation we will not be able to edit the file. How would I go about editing the CSS for this - For example I have a div named 'services' with a background image for this div in the CSS. How would this be implemented from within WP?

Comment: You should read about the Wordpress Template Hierarchy, here is an infographic illustrating the fallbacks. https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think you got it wrong, wordpress works on themes. In order to make your html design work with wordpress you will first have to create theme. Creating a basic theme is as simple as creating a new folder. Here are some of the basic files that are important, and difference between index.php and front-page.php.

1. style.css, This file will contain some comments that will define
   the details about your theme
2. Header.php, The header part of your html design goes in this file including the main menu and slider.
3. Footer.php, the footer part i.e. copyright statements, footer menu etc goes in here
4. index.php, this file is used by default for list of blogs, but you can change it from settings > reading > and then choose the page you want to show as home page.
5. front-page.php, this is similar to what index.php does but it has more priority. So if both the files are present then this will be used. Another advantage of front-page.php is that you can add any kind of hardcoded html in here as it is not used by any other page.
6. page.php, this file is used to show all content of wordpress pages, like about, contact etc.
7. single.php, this file is responsible for showing a single blog post.